# adjust size of frame components in swings when it is maximized

Tags: java, swing, layout, frame

Hello Please tell me the code to size frame components in swings so that they get same screen percentage as provide before.

I have used Three panels one main and other are subpanels.The main menu has border layout.One submenu has border and other gridlayout.When I maximize the window the upper panel moves upward and bottom one sticks to the bottom 
My code.:

```
JPanel mainPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); 
mainPane.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 mainPane.add(chatPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: Please tell us your code

Comment: Why not use `GridLayout` with `2 Row 1 Column` for the `mainPane` too, that way this will not happen :-)

Answer (score 1):

In Swing, you can use **layout managers** to have your components resized as you want.
Probably the most used for this cases is `BorderLayout`:

```
JFrame myframe = new JFrame("Hello world!");
myframe.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
myframe.setSize(500,500);

//The CENTER component expands whenever the window is resized
myframe.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea()), BorderLayout.CENTER);

//The other components don't expand, they shrink to their minimum size
myframe.add(new JButton("Do something"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
myframe.add(new JButton("Click me"), BorderLayout.NORTH);

myframe.setVisible(true);
```

I recommend you to see [the Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). It's an excellent resource to get you started.